# Hdfs to s3 Distcp - Access Keys

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, distcp

For copying the file from HDFS to S3 bucket I used the command

```
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3a.access.key=ACCESS_KEY_HERE\
-Dfs.s3a.secret.key=SECRET_KEY_HERE /path/in/hdfs s3a:/BUCKET NAME
```

But the access key and sectet key are visible here which are not secure .
Is there any method to provide credentials from file .
I dont want to edit config file ,which is one of the method I came across .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent (2.8+) versions let you hide your credentials in a jceks file; there's some documentation on the Hadoop s3 page there. That way: no need to put any secrets on the command line at all; you just share them across the cluster and then, in the distcp command, set `hadoop.security.credential.provider.path` to the path, like `jceks://hdfs@nn1.example.com:9001/user/backup/s3.jceks`

Fan: if you are running in EC2, the IAM role credentials should be automatically picked up from the default chain of credential providers: after looking for the config options & env vars, it tries a GET of the EC2 http endpoint which serves up the session credentials. If that's not happening, make sure that `com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` is on the list of credential providers. It's a bit slower than the others (and can get throttled), so best to put near the end.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same situation, and after got temporary credentials from matadata instance. (in case you're using IAM User's credential, please notice that the temporary credentials mentioned here is IAM Role, which attach to EC2 server not human, refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

I found only specifying the credentials in the `hadoop distcp` cmd will not work.
You also have to specify a config `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider`. (refer http://hortonworks.github.io/hdp-aws/s3-security/index.html#using-temporary-session-credentials)

Final command will look like below

```
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider="org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider" -Dfs.s3a.access.key="{AccessKeyId}" -Dfs.s3a.secret.key="{SecretAccessKey}" -Dfs.s3a.session.token="{SessionToken}" s3a://bucket/prefix/file /path/on/hdfs
```

Comment: Commented on this in my answer. If you are running in EC2, you shouldn't need to declare credentials here unless you want different ones from the EC2 IAM roles

Comment: @SteveLoughran Thanks for your answer.  hmm, I forgot to mention I was running the hadoop cmd from Airflow, and use IAM assume-role feature for the security management.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon allows to generate temporary credentials that you can retrieve from http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/

you can read [from there](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials)

> An application on the instance retrieves the security credentials provided by the role from the instance metadata item *iam/security-credentials/role-name*. The application is granted the permissions for the actions and resources that you've defined for the role through the security credentials associated with the role. These security credentials are temporary and we rotate them automatically. We make new credentials available at least five minutes prior to the expiration of the old credentials.

The following command retrieves the security credentials for an IAM role named s3access.

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access
```

The following is example output.

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2012-04-26T16:39:16Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
  "Token" : "token",
  "Expiration" : "2012-04-27T22:39:16Z"
}
```

> For applications, AWS CLI, and Tools for Windows PowerShell commands that run on the instance, you do not have to explicitly get the temporary security credentials — the AWS SDKs, AWS CLI, and Tools for Windows PowerShell automatically get the credentials from the EC2 instance metadata service and use them. To make a call outside of the instance using temporary security credentials (for example, to test IAM policies), you must provide the access key, secret key, and the session token. For more information, see [Using Temporary Security Credentials to Request Access to AWS Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html) in the IAM User Guide.

Comment: I didnt get it from this article ,can you elaborate , my question is is there any way we can pass these credential through the file directly

Comment: well you can't but you can use temporary key - so you would need to read the temp keys from the url and pass them to the command line

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use access and secret key (or show them on your scripts) and if your EC2 instance has access to S3 then you can use the instance credentials

```
hadoop distcp \
-Dfs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider="com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider" \
/hdfs_folder/myfolder \
s3a://bucket/myfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is because of a version difference, but to use "secrets from credential providers" the `-Dfs` flag would not work for me, I had to use the `-D` flag as shown on the [hadoop version 3.1.3 "Using_secrets_from_credential_providers" docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Using_secrets_from_credential_providers).

First I saved my AWS S3 credentials in a Java Cryptography Extension KeyStore (JCEKS) file.

```
hadoop credential create fs.s3a.access.key \
-provider jceks://hdfs/user/$USER/s3.jceks \
-value <my_AWS_ACCESS_KEY>

hadoop credential create fs.s3a.secret.key \
-provider jceks://hdfs/user/$USER/s3.jceks \
-value <my_AWS_SECRET_KEY>
```

Then the following `distcp` command format worked for me.

```
hadoop distcp \
-D hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/$USER/s3.jceks \
/hdfs_folder/myfolder \
s3a://bucket/myfolder
```